# User registration without email address OR registration with pseudo-email address

Tags: 8, users

I am programmatically creating users for the roles Parent (Adult) & Child (minor). During registration, minors (Children) typically will not have email addresses but Drupal user registration requires email address.

During registration of minor, unfortunately, the adults email address cannot be reused based on Drupal’s one email rule.

My queries are as follows:

1. Is it possible that we can create users without email address?
2. If not 1. can we use some pseudo-email address that we can created for each minor. However, emails for any minor should be sent to the adults address instead.

Comment: Email is not required. The uid is the global identifier. But of course you have to make sure the email is unique since it is used in password reset or user_load_by_mail. for example when drupal is being installed the admin has no email until the admin submits the site configuration form during the installation process.

Comment: @sukhjinder-singh I'd be interested to know what your use-case was and how you solved this problem. I'm guessing it was for a school?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an email address, but I could be wrong about this.

You can definitely provide a fake email address though.

For example, you can use `hook_form_alter()` to modify the registration form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Hide the mail form
  $form['account']['mail']['#access'] = FALSE;
  // Set the email address to minor+UID@mydomain.com
  // You need to write this code yourself...
```

Make sure you set the email address to include the UID or something similar that will ensure the email is unique; Drupal has to have a unique email for each account.

Then, use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/8.4.x) to check the user's role and, if the user is a minor, query the parent's email address and send the parent an email instead.