# Drop UserMailRequired constraint

Tags: 8, users, forms

In my Drupal site, only administrators create users. And users are created without an email. Users can edit themselves some of their account fields, but the email is not one of them.

But the user module adds a `UserMailRequired` constraint to the User entity email field. On submit, the user module's validator `UserMailRequiredValidator` adds a violation if the current user is not an administrator :

```
class UserMailRequiredValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface $items */
    /** @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface $account */
    $account = $items->getEntity();
    $existing_value = NULL;
    if ($account->id()) {
      $account_unchanged = \Drupal::entityManager()
        ->getStorage('user')
        ->loadUnchanged($account->id());
      $existing_value = $account_unchanged->getEmail();
    }

    $required = !(!$existing_value && \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer users'));

    if ($required && (!isset($items) || $items->isEmpty())) {
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, ['@name' => $account->getFieldDefinition('mail')->getLabel()]);
    }
  }

}
```

So, none of my user can edit its profile. On submit, they get an error message "Email field is required". Even if the field's `#required` property is set to false (using hook_form_alter) and the field not displayed (`#access` = false) in the form render array.

How can I drop this constraint from a custom module ? (using a hook for example)

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/250302/57

Comment: Setting fake email adresses during registration is not a good solution for me. As I said, administrators can already create accounts without an email adress. What I need is to drop the validation of this field when I submit `user_form` form.

Comment: Did you solve this. I just ran into it. No amount of changing #required in form alter works. I'm thinking the Plugin class has to be extended and changed. Wondering if you've already solved this @Eria

Comment: @eahonet : unfortunately, I don't remember :/ That was one year ago, and I'm not working on this project anymore. And I don't have access to the source code. Sorry...

Answer (score 4):

For those that find themselves here trying to make User Emails Optional, use hook_validation_constraint_alter. You're not extending core's, you're creating a new constraint and using it instead of core's. In my case, I replace core's with... an empty function to achieve what I want.

Something like this in .module

```
function optional_account_email_validation_constraint_alter(array &$definitions) {
  $definitions['UserMailRequired']['class'] = '\Drupal\my_module_name\Constraint\OverrideUserMailRequired';
}
```

Then a copy of the two UserMailRequiredValidator.php and UserMailRequired.php files changed to your liking.

The module administerusersbyrole has a working example of this.

I'll see if I can get around to putting my custom module onto drupal.org in the coming months.

Comment: This is the wrong hook to implement, to remove a constraint. `hook_entity_base_field_info_alter()` is the one that allows to remove constraints. It has the pro that allows to remove a constraint from the field of a specific entity type, which is helpful when the constraint is added to different entity types and changing the constraint for all the entity types isn't desired.